# ExUnit Assertions

Tags: elixir, ex-unit

In the test cases we use assertions to handle errors. Match their return value with what we defined and the test will pass. like if we have an argument error we use this:

```
 assert_raise ArgumentError, "argument error", fn ->
```

This will work and test will pass. If we have `ArgumentError`. Same is the case with `RuntimeError`

But if we have long error messages like this:

```
 exception Postgrex.Error (ERROR 42703 (undefined_column): column 
 j0.rating does not exist)
```

How can we handle these kind of long exception messages in our test cases?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to assert the message inside the exception, you can call `assert_raise/2`:

```
assert_raise Postgrex.Error, fn ->
  ...
end
```

If you want to only match a part of the exception message, you can pass a regex to `assert_raise/3`:

```
assert_raise Postgrex.Error, ~r/undefined_column/, fn ->
  ...
end
```

Comment: Thanks thats a simple solution.